# Where can we find udiskd's logs?

Tags: udisks

I want to see the udisksd's logs, where does it get stored and how to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the logs with `journalctl`, thusly:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ locate udisksd
/usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd
/usr/share/man/man8/udisksd.8.gz
walt@bat:~(0)$ journalctl /usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. May I know  how I can get debug level of logs?<br/> Even after removing --no-debug, from udisks2.service file, not able to get debug logs.

Comment: Did you restart the server? BTW, asking a second question in the comments is discouraged. It hides the second question (and any answer, also in the comments) from the AskUbuntu Question search. This does NOT help future users.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
journalctl -u udisks2.service
```

and then apply filters according to your need